# visualize_velocity_profile.py not working in teb_local_planner?

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`$`

```
rosrun teb_local_planner_tutorials visualize_velocity_profile.py
```

Output:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named visualize_velocity_profile.py below                 /home/chacha/glocal/src/teb_local_planner_tutorials
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/chacha/glocal/src/teb_local_planner_tutorials/scripts/visualize_velocity_profile.py
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258154/visualize_velocity_profile.py-not-working-in-teb_local_planner??/) by [anirudhyadav1001](https://answers.ros.org/users/28152/anirudhyadav1001/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @anirudhyadav1001!

The error happens because your file doesn't have "execute permissions".

In order to solve that, you can give "execute permissions" using the command below:

```
chmod +x visualize_velocity_profile.py
```

Now, if you call `rosrun teb_local_planner_tutorials visualize_velocity_profile.py` again it should work.

If you prefer, I've [created a video](https://youtu.be/WJlN95ce--o) where we give and remove "execute permissions" to confirm that this is the reason behind the error.

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2